# Proper way of recovering a Postgres database from a PGdata folder?

Tags: database, postgresql, restore

My PC has its OS reinstalled recently. I'm left with the PGdata folder of a Postgres server that was locally hosted.

Could anyone explain how to recover all the data therein? My first intuition was to start a new server and replace its new PGdata folder with the old one but this seems somewhat barbaric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the PostgreSQL version, the operating system and the machine architecture match, you can simply start PostgreSQL against the existing data directory:

```
pg_ctl start -D /path/to/your/data
```

Comment: This technically answers my question, but I get an error message "Only usage of each socket address is normally permitted". I am not sure how to go about troubleshooting this but I guess it would constitute a different question.

Comment: There is no such error message in PostgreSQL. Are you sure that is the correct wording? If the problem is that there is already a different PostgreSQL server running on the same machine with the same TCP port, eit `postgresql.conf` and change the `port` parameter (or use `pg_stl start -D ... -o '-p 5555'`).

Comment: You were right. Tech support installed the wrong version of PostgreSQL and put in on auto-start. Can't kill it because I don't have admin privileges but changing ports worked. You literally just saved me days of pointless work. Thank you!!